# riotjs: nested <inner-html> tag not working

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm trying to build an extended set of custom components for handling form elements. To start with I wanted to create a `form-components` custom tag, that handles showing of label (and later some basic validation rules) and then specific components.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/publicJorn/omvbxor0/) you can see it set up. I'm using the [nested tags](https://muut.com/riotjs/guide/#nested-html) example to copy nodes from the parent tag to the child tag. However, this only seems to work 1 deep.

I'm doubting wether my approach is the right way to go and this just isn't supported, or I'm just looking at it from the wrong direction.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: I have the same issue. Tried this way, and yet not working: https://muut.com/riotjs/guide/#nested-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated your fiddle to riot.js v2.0.15 and replaced the `<inner-html/>` tag with the new `<yield/>` tag and it seems to work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e3p9n4pd/

Answer (score -1):

"yield" tag is usefull if we are trying to access the inner text of tag within the HTML code of tag definition. but if we have to acces that text in scri